# Download manager is not working on real device

Tags: java, android

```
 DownloadManager downloadManager;
                downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

download file is working fine in emulator but not work on real device

Comment: Check URL. It must not be localhost url.

Comment: what i dont understand

Comment: url is fine it is hosted

Answer (score 1):

Did you add permission to the AndroidManifest.xml?
It happened to me and i solved like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: which type of permision